# How to install sql2005 on sql2008r2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am poorly experienced in SQL Server installations. I have already installed 2008r2 on Microsoft Windows 8.

Now I want to install MS SQL Server 2005, but I need both MS SQL Server 2008r2 and MS SQL Server 2005.

How can I install this?

Comment: Why would you wanna install SQL 2005? It just ran out of support..

Answer (score 0):

You can install both versions on same computer..

**From MSDN:**

> SQL Server supports multiple instances of the Database Engine, Analysis Services, and Reporting Services on the same computer. You can also upgrade earlier versions of SQL Server, or install SQL Server on a computer where earlier SQL Server versions are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems here; firstly SQL 2005 isn't even compatible with Windows 8. Windows 7 you can just about get away with it with some patching. Next you need to install the instances and tools in version order. So SQL 2005, then SQL 2008.

You could try uninstalling SQL2008, but you'll probably find too many updates and bits have occurred to get back to a state that might allow you to try doing SQL2005.

My recommendation would be; format the host machine. Install Windows 8. Setup HyperV virtual machines for each version of SQL Server in an operating system that's more inline with the SQL product. Eg. Win2003 for SQL2005. Win2008 for SQL 2008.

He's a block post of doing this to create a manageable developer workstation running every version of SQL Server: http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/05/using-hyper-v-and-powershell-to-create-the-perfect-developer-workstation/